# Response of a seismic array

Tags: exponential-function

I need to prove:
$$\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\sin(\omega t-r\gamma)=\dfrac{\sin(\frac{1}{2}n\gamma)}{\sin(\frac{1}{2}\gamma)}\sin[\omega t-\dfrac{1}{2}(n-1)\gamma]$$

Hint: $\cos x-i\sin x=e^{-ix}$

Comment: What does this have to do with "response of a array"?  And why do you place that in the title?  And what have you tried?

Comment: * Response of a seismic array....

Comment: $$ \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\sin(\omega t-r\gamma)=\text{Im}\left(\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}e^{i(\omega t-r\gamma)}\right) $$

Comment: Why does this question need to mention "seismic array"?